# run wordpress endpoint from within iframe

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, iframe, wordpress-rest-api

Let me try to explain my problem. A third party made a wordpress side. When the user push a button, my software will run within an iframe. It is made in react, just for information. When the user selected an item and push the order button, I have to check first if this user is logged in that wordpress site. I searched and find things like: `is_user_logged_in` function but than I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() <br/><br/>
```

When I use postman and I call: `.../wp-json/wp/v2/pages` then I get the information. When I try to do this within my code, I get something like: `301 Moved Permanently`

So I was wondering, is it even possible from within an iframe to use wordpress rest api?

Greetings

Comment: Are WordPress installation and iFrame src using the same domain name?

Comment: No, the wordpress runs on a different domain than my software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use the WP REST API from within an iframe but since you're trying to make that request from one domain to another, you need to explicitly allow that in the WP installation by setting the appropriate headers to allow [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). The simplest and fastest way to do this, is to add something like this to your `functions.php`:

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

Though you should probably limit that to only the domain(s) needed any maybe even add the header for select requests only.

If your request targets the same domain the user logged in to, session cookies should be added to your request automatically, so WordPress can verify if the current user was indeed logged in. I suggest to create a dedicated REST route for that exact purpose and return all the information necessary for whatever is in your iframe to work.